# Is my proof correct that function is a bijection iff matrix is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For given $B\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ let's define a function $$f: \mathbb{C}^{n\times n} \to \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$$
so that $$f(A) = B^HAB$$ I have to prove that f is a bijection iff B is invertible.

Is my proof correct?

$1)$ Suppose f is a bijection so $$\forall A \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}  \exists A' $$ that $$f(A') = A$$
then
$$B^HA'B=A$$ so $$A'=(B^H)^{-1}AB^{-1}$$
Therefore $B$ have to be invertible because we have to invert it to get $A'$

$2)$ Suppose B is invertible $$\forall A\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n} f((B^H)^{-1}AB^{-1}) = B^H(B^H)^{-1}AB^{-1}B = A$$
It's true that we can get any $A$ by taking $(B^H)^{-1}AB^{-1}$ as an argument so $f$ is surjective

Let $X,Y \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ and $X\not= Y$ so it's trye that $B^HXB\not=B^HYB$ so $f(X)\not=f(Y)$ therefore $f$ is injective. To conclude, $f$ is a bijection

Comment: Your proof will look cleaner if you show $f(X) = f(Y)$ implies $X = Y$ instead. Also, a minor justification why $(B^{H})^{-1}$ may or may not be necessary depending on what this is for.

Comment: Your proof for 1) is not valid as stated.  You've shown that if $B$ is invertible, then you *can* find $f^{-1}$, but not that $B$ being invertible is necessary.

Comment: Any hint how to start proving it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof for 1) is flawed, as I've stated in a comment.  Here's are two ways to prove it properly:

---

Suppose that $f$ is a bijection.  Then there exists an $A$ such that $f(A) = I$.  That is,
$$
B^HAB = I
$$
Then, we note that
$$
n = \operatorname{rank}(I) = \operatorname{rank}(B^HAB) \leq 
\min\{\operatorname{rank} B^H,\operatorname{rank} A,\operatorname{rank} B\} \leq
\operatorname{rank} B
$$
that is, $B$ has full rank, which means that it must be invertible.

---

Suppose that $B$ is not invertible.  Then $B^H$ has a non-trivial kernel. So, there exists a non-zero $x \in \Bbb C^n$ such that $B^Hx = 0$.  It follows that
$$
f(x x^H) = B^H xx^H B = (B^H x)(B^H x)^H = 00^H = 0 =f(0)
$$
so, $f$ is not injective, and therefore not a bijection.